# "2 месяцев назад" не "2 месяца назад"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На данной странице [Perl. Формат строки с числом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472813/perl-%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC) можно увидеть вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно заменить "2 месяцев назад" на "2 месяц**а** назад" и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Поправил. Сроки будут доступны после ближайшего развертывания движка.